# Python - Replace characters for emoticons

Tags: python, regex

```
l = ':;\'"!@#$%^&*()_-=+][{}~`.><?/\\|' # list of character that can be used for emoticons

s = '<p>This :) is an example for:) emoticons :)</p>'
```

I used `s.replace(':)', '<img>')` and,

```
result = '<p>this <img> is an example for<img> emoticons <img></p>'
```

How to make the result like:

```
result = '<p>this <img> is an example for:) emoticons <img></p>'
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: I have a initial list `l`. Users can only make a emoticon from characters in `l`. For example: `:)`, `:]`, ect. With each emoticon, I will change it to an image respectively in response. So users must enter data correctly: the wildcard should stand alone. The hard part is the input data include HTML tags.

Comment: Be more specific. Do you want to only make the replacement when the "<img>" substring is surrounded by whitespace? You want "for:)" to turn into "for"?

Comment: i do not know too much python, but i think you can do on this following way : 1) first search for second '<img>' and return this index 2) you could separate into two parts s[1-index] s[(index + 4)-length(s)] 3) now you could use replace().

Comment: Wait- it's still not clear. You're saying that you only want to make replacements when there is whitespace before it?

Comment: Yeah. Instead of just an example, it would be more helpful to specify exactly what rules you want the code to follow.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: I tried this regex: `re.sub(r'\b(%s)\b' % i, '<img>', s)`. But it does not work. It should work if `i` is alphabet.

Comment: \b only matches at the beginning of a word. Do you want \s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
emos = { ':)' : 'smiley.jpg',
         ':(' : 'saddy.jpg',
         ';p' : 'bllinky.jpg' }
pattern = re.compile('|'.join( re.escape(emo) for emo in emos))
def emoImg(emoMatch):
    return '<img src = "/images/{0}>'.format(emos[emoMatch.group(0)])
def emoSub(string):
    return pattern.sub(emoImg,string)
print(emoSub('Hi :) I miss you :('))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = '<p>This :) is an example for:) emoticons :)</p>'
>>> s.replace(' :)', ' <img>')
'<p>This <img> is an example for:) emoticons <img></p>'
```

If you only want to make replacements where the pattern is has a leading space, put a leading space around both the match and the substitution.

Comment: Brenden and I have accomplished the same thing with our answers: his ' :)' is equivalent to my '\s:\\)' (\s is one whitespace, and :\\) is :) with the ) escaped). Props to him for doing this w/o dragging regex into it; however, if your use case is more complicated than this, you may in fact have to start using regexes.

Comment: Very true. I just solved the trivial case. Anything more complex, and regexes are where it's at.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s = '<p>This :) is an example for:) emoticons :)</p>'
s = re.sub('\s:\)', ' <img>',s)
```